# How can I make the curve's arrow pointing the right direction

Tags: tikz-arrows

[image]

As figure.

I hope the final arrow can point the right direction.

`\draw [-latex,thin] plot [smooth] coordinates {(-4.98,1.95/2+0.1) (1,0.716) (1.1,-1.19) (-2.6,-1.2)};`

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [-latex,thin] plot [smooth] coordinates {(-4.98,1.95/2+0.1) (1,0.716)
                (1.1,-1.19) (-2.6,-1.2)};
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: While snippets are useful, it is advisable to add complete code starting from `\documentclass{..}.........\end{document}` as it helps those who want to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is the same as at [Smooth option sometimes produces incorrect arrow tips in PGFplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19642/smooth-option-sometimes-produces-incorrect-arrow-tips-in-pgfplots). Using the solution presented there you obtain the desired results:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\def\pgf@plot@curveto@handler@finish{%
  \ifpgf@plot@started%
    \pgfpathcurvebetweentimecontinue{0}{0.995}{\pgf@plot@curveto@first}{\pgf@plot@curveto@first@support}{\pgf@plot@curveto@second}{\pgf@plot@curveto@second}%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [-latex,thin] plot [smooth] coordinates {(-4.98,1.95/2+0.1) (1,0.716)
                (1.1,-1.19) (-2.6,-1.2)};
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
```