# Problem with curved lines in three dimensions

Tags: tikz-arrows

I want to indicate the lenght of the s curve. Used the smooth algorithm in the same way but the curve does not seem "smooth":

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [
        >=stealth,
        cm={-1,-1,1,0,(0,0)},
        x=3.85mm,
        z=-1cm, 
        axis/.style={-, black}, 
        vector/.style={-{Stealth[length=6,width=3]}, very thick, black}
    ] 

    \draw (0,0,0) node[left]{$O$};
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (4,0,0) node[left]{$X$};
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,4,0) node[right]{$Y$};
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,4) node[left]{$Z$};

    \draw[vector] (0,0,0) -- (1,1,2) node[circle,fill,inner    sep=0.7pt,label=left:$ A $](){};
    \draw (0.5,0.5,1) node[right]{$ \vec{r}_{0} $};
    \draw[vector] (0,0,0) -- (2.5,4,2.5) node[circle,fill,inner sep=0.7pt,label=right:$ B $](){};
    \draw (1.25,2,1.25) node[below]{$ \vec{r}(t) $};
    \draw[vector] (1,1,2) -- (2.5,4,2.5);
    \draw (1.75,2.25,2.25) node[below]{$ \Delta \vec{r} $};
    \draw [thick] plot [smooth, tension=1] coordinates { (1,1,2) (1.75,2.5,2.5) (2.5,4,2.5)};
    \draw [>=Bracket, <->] plot [smooth, tension=1] coordinates { (1,1,2.25) (1.75,2.5,2.75) (2.5,4,2.75)};
    \draw (1.75,2.5,2.5) node[above]{$ s $};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the result: [image: Result]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please be so kind to always include a minimum *working* example. so add the `\documentclass` and stuff so it is compilable. Also, images help a lot. I added both for you.
Then, for me, it is not really clear what you want to achieve. Shouldn't the length of the curve be a straight line? However, i would suggest drawing the curved line with the `arc` operation, not with `plot`. In my opinion, plot is always quite akward to handle.

Comment: Sorry about that and thank you for the recommendations, I will consider them for my next post.

Comment: No problem! It's a hint, it's not meant negative or mean :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so the issue is not with the coordinates or anything else, is with the `plot` path specifier handling arrow tips, it's covered here: [Smooth option sometimes produces incorrect arrow tips in PGFplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19642/smooth-option-sometimes-produces-incorrect-arrow-tips-in-pgfplots). Jake provides a solution for adding arrow tips to PGFplots, specifically.

Since you're using TikZ it won't work. But I have a workaround. First, since the plot with `Brackets` is the same as the one below, you should use the `shift` option, makes the drawing more concise. Alright, now that we know the problem occurs when we add arrow tips, we'll simply draw without tips and add them later:

```
\draw[>={Bracket[]}, postaction={<->, tips=true}, shift={(0,0,.25)}] plot[smooth,...
```

The key `tips=true` overwrites the rules for adding arrow tips forcing TikZ to add arrows even if there's no drawing. The result is:

[image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [
        >=stealth,
        cm={-1,-1,1,0,(0,0)},
        x=3.85mm,
        z=-1cm, 
        axis/.style={-, black}, 
        vector/.style={-{Stealth[length=6,width=3]}, very thick, black}
    ] 

    \draw (0,0,0) node[left]{$O$};
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (4,0,0) node[left]{$X$};
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,4,0) node[right]{$Y$};
    \draw[axis] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,4) node[left]{$Z$};

    \draw[vector] (0,0,0) -- (1,1,2) node[circle,fill,inner    sep=0.7pt,label=left:$ A $](){};
    \draw (0.5,0.5,1) node[right]{$ \vec{r}_{0} $};
    \draw[vector] (0,0,0) -- (2.5,4,2.5) node[circle,fill,inner sep=0.7pt,label=right:$ B $](){};
    \draw (1.25,2,1.25) node[below]{$ \vec{r}(t) $};
    \draw[vector] (1,1,2) -- (2.5,4,2.5);
    \draw (1.75,2.25,2.25) node[below]{$ \Delta \vec{r} $};
    \draw [thick] plot [smooth, tension=1] coordinates { (1,1,2) (1.75,2.5,2.5) (2.5,4,2.5)};
    \draw [>={Bracket[]}, postaction={<->, tips=true}, shift={(0,0,.25)}] plot [smooth, tension=1] coordinates { (1,1,2) (1.75,2.5,2.5) (2.5,4,2.5) };
    \draw (1.75,2.5,2.5) node[above]{$ s $};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and work. I appreciate this.

Comment: You are very much welcome. Though we encourage users to thank others for help by upvoting helpful answers and questions and, when possible, accepting the answer which was most helpful. :)